# choose the specific variable in r

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

There are data like this table:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15

4  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0

1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0

2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0

1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0

2  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

and I wish to make a new matrix with the specific variable columns which have a numerical value different from zero (in this case the specific variable columns are v1 and v4).

I know the subset function but I cannot find the way to choose conditional columns by using "if statement".

I mean... how can I make a matrix with only the specific columns that have numerical value different from zero by using "if statement"?

Please help me to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what format your data is in, but if you have a matrix or a data.frame, you should be able to use the [R extract operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) (`[`) to specify only the columns you want.  You can feed it a vector of logical values (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) for that specification, so all you need is a function that will return the logical values you want.

As a simple example with a matrix, you could apply a function seeing if there are any non-zero values across each of the columns of the matrix:

```
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    0    4
[2,]    0    2    0    5
[3,]    0    3    0    6

> a[, apply(a, 2, function(x) { return(any(x != 0)) })]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
```

This same extract mechanism works on data.frames as well:

```
> a
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  0  1  0  4
2  0  2  0  5
3  0  3  0  6
> a[, sapply(a, function(x) { return(any(x != 0)) })]
  V2 V4
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6
```